# Undefined reference to non-member function - C++

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors

I have the following in header file.

```
namespace silc{
   class pattern_token_map
   {
      /* Contents */
   };

   pattern_token_map* load_from_file(const char*);
}
```

In the CPP file (this has got proper includes)

```
pattern_token_map* load_from_file(const char* filename)
{
   // Implementation goes here
}
```

In another CPP file. This has got all proper includes.

```
void some_method()
{
    const char* filename = "sample.xml";
    pattern_token_map* map = load_from_file( filename ); // Linker complains about this.
}
```

I am getting a linker error saying that undefined reference to `load_from_file`. I am not able to see what is going wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Compiler : G++
OS : Ubuntu 9.10

**Edit**

Here is the linker command used.

```
g++ -L/home/nkn/silc-project/third_party/UnitTest++ -o tests.out  src/phonetic_kit/pattern_token_map.o  tests/pattern_token_map_tests.o  tests/main.o -lUnitTest++
```

Error is from `pattern_token_map_tests.o` and the function is available in `pattern_token_map.o`. So I guess the order of linking is not making the problem. (I have removed some files from the command to simplify it)

Comment: Are you missing the parens on `some_method`?

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you have posted - please add the compiler/linker command you are using.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I have added linker command which I am using. It is a simplified version of what I have.

Comment: If you "nm pattern_token_map.o | grep load_from_file", what do you see?

Comment: I have edited the code to say that method is in a namespace called silc. @Andreas: No, I am not using templates.

Comment: @Richard: Output of grep : `00000065 T _Z14load_from_filePKc`. And I have proper namespace includes in the CPP file.

Comment: Is `load_from_file`'s implementation defined inside a `namespace silc` block?

Comment: Great. I was not adding the methods implementation in to namespace silc. Thanks Peter for pointing it out. If you could add it as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies for stealing your thunder Peter, hadn't seen your comment.

Comment: You can take Roger's answer; he explained it better than I was going  to! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you implement it, you have to make sure you implement the right function:

```
namespace silc {
pattern_token_map* load_from_file(const char* filename) {
   // Implementation goes here
}
}
```

If you instead did this:

```
using namespace silc; // to get pattern_token_map
pattern_token_map* load_from_file(const char* filename) {
   // Implementation goes here
}
```

Then you'd be defining a *new function* rather than silc::load_from_file.

Avoid using directives ("using namespace ...;") outside of function scope, as a general guideline:

```
using namespace silc; // outside function scope: avoid

silc::pattern_token_map*                      // qualify return type
random_function(silc::pattern_token_map* p) { // and parameters
  using namespace silc; // inside function scope: fine
  pattern_token_map* p2 = 0; // don't have to qualify inside the function
                             // if you want to use the using directive
  silc::pattern_token_map* p3 = 0; // but you can always do this
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. By saying "Avoid using directives ("using namespace ...;") outside of functions.", do you mean that avoid writing it on top of cpp files. Write it inside each functions instead. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use it inside a function, that's fine.  You rarely need it anyway, as you can use the form in my first piece of code to implement your functions in cpp files.

Comment: I hadn't thought of restricting `using` directives to inside function bodies. +1

Comment: While this advice is considered good coding practice by most, be advised that it's incredibly annoying to follow.

Answer (score 0):

In your link phase, are you linking in the object file created by compiling the first cpp file? Linker errors like these occur when one object references a symbol that is not included in the objects being linked.

Edit: I'm still reasonably confident that this is the problem. In the first file, is there a preprocessor symbol redefining load_from_file?

Comment: Yes. I am linking all the object files. Added the linker command. Please have a look.